# How to handle mouse right click on QSystemTrayIcon?

Tags: c++, qt, mouseevent, qsystemtrayicon

I have connected QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason to my 'handleClick' slot as below

```
connect(tray,SIGNAL(activated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)), this,SLOT(handleClick(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)));

mywindow::handleClick(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason reason)
{
    switch (reason)
    {
    case QSystemTrayIcon::Trigger:
    case QSystemTrayIcon::DoubleClick:
        handleLeftClickOnTray();
        break;
    case QSystemTrayIcon::MiddleClick:
        break;
    default:;
    }
}
```

I have another function called 'handleRightClickOnSystemTray()' which should be called when mouse right button clicked over system tray icon. This function creates a QDialog box and display it. How to handle right click mouse events on system tray ?

Comment: Avoid the `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros in new code using a modern version of Qt. They are slow, are not compile-time-checked and require `moc` to work. Prefer the new, compile time checked, pointer to member function syntax instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [QSystemTrayIcon::Trigger](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html#ActivationReason-enum) which will be invoked when you left click. [QSystemTrayIcon::DoubleClick](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html#ActivationReason-enum) will not trigger when a menu is in place.

```
 case QSystemTrayIcon::Trigger:
    qDebug() << "Left clicked";
 break;
```

If that's not working for you, then you have to reimplement [bool QSystemTrayIcon::event(QEvent *e)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html#event) and install an event filter to check which button was pressed.

The new signal and slot syntax is

```
connect(tray, &QSystemTrayIcoon::activated, this, &MainWindow::handleClick /* assuming it's MainWindow */);
```

or the lamba version

```
connect(tray, &QSystemTrayIcoon::activated, [](QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason reason) { switch(reason) { /* .. */ } });
```

Comment: You are mentioning about Left click. Yes I can handle left click on `QSystemTrayIcon::Trigger`.  But my concern is how to handle right click ? Do we require to install event for that ? It would be great, if you could provide a small code snippet.

Comment: @ GUI-Novice: Please read your question. You clearly say `How to handle left click on system tray ?`. An answer was given to your question.

Comment: @ GUI-Novice for right-click you may subclass QSystemTrayIcon and override/reimplement `event`. The QEvent parameter should tell you the mouse button that was used.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake.I have edited my question title.

Comment: Double click events are not triggered even if no menu is in place, only middle click and trigger events are detected, I don't know if it's on my end or something more.

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround if you don't need The context menu of your system tray icon.

You can use `QMenu`'s signal [`void QMenu::aboutToShow()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmenu.html#aboutToShow), it detects right clicks, but you have to keep your menu without actions so that it does not actually `show`, you'll just be using its `mouse event` without displaying it.

This basically will make it as if your `QSystemTrayIcon` handled your right click mouse event.

Here's an example:

```
QSystemTrayIcon TrayIcon( QIcon("favicon.png") );
QMenu menu;

TrayIcon.show();
TrayIcon.setContextMenu(&menu);
QObject::connect(&menu,&QMenu::aboutToShow,some_function);
```